# Do we need the tag [ noaa-prime]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

Do we need the tag [noaa-prime](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noaa-prime)  ( it has only one question ) ?

but we still   have some related tags [artificial-satellite](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-satellite) .

I think [noaa-prime](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noaa-prime) can be deleted and the question must be retagged or can be made tag synonyms of [artificial-satellite](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-satellite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to judge how many questions will make use of a particular tag in the future, but I have to say I tend to agree it might be slightly too specific, and it mightn't find many future uses. However, we do have other tags that further differentiate between various artificial satellite   types, be it by their purpose / function, design / size, e.t.c. and they seem to be used frequently enough (having in mind the total number of questions we currently have).

This said, I think this tag [noaa-prime](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noaa-prime) designating NOAA-19, the last in the NOAA (National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration) POES (Polar Operational Environmental Satellite) series of satellites could be simply renamed to have its use slightly less restrictive to this individual satellite.

TL;DR - Count this as a proposal to rename the tag [noaa-prime](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noaa-prime) to [noaa](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noaa), and add another tag [poes](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poes) to the list of the question's tags. Any tag renames will automatically reflect on the questions using them.

---

**Update**: I went ahead and retagged that question:

[failure](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/failure) [integration](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration) <s>[noaa-prime](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noaa-prime)</s> → [failure](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/failure) [integration](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration) [noaa](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noaa) [poes](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poes)

<sup>Note tho, that this could have been done by anyone, since the tag in question was only used with a single question and didn't have a tag wiki, and any renaming of a single use tag with an edit (or a suggested edit, if not having enough reputation to edit posts directly without approval) would reflect in having a new tag (whatever it was renamed to) and the old one gone (i.e. not used by any questions). I'm saying this in a bid to try and avoid too much of the red tape here in our meta, when changes are unlikely to be disputed and edits indeed are an improvement to the question itself, or how we organize tags on our website. Do mind though, not to rename tags like this when they already have their community wikis (excerpt, or the full wiki body), not to create orphan wikis. In this case though, no wiki was submitted for the tag, so this was fine to do like that. If however tags have wikis, then the procedure should be notifying any of the moderators (by flagging the question with a custom reason, or also in our [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay)) that have the tools available to rename tags and keep them associated with their wikis. Thanks!</sup>